# How to search in an array with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-match

How do I search in an array with preg_match?

Example:

```
<?php
if( preg_match( '/(my\n+string\n+)/i' , array( 'file' , 'my string  => name', 'this') , $match) )
{
    //Excelent!!
    $items[] = $match[1];
} else {
    //Ups! not found!
}
?>
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

*In this post I'll provide you with three different methods of doing what you ask for. I actually recommend using the last snippet, since it's easiest to comprehend as well as being quite neat in code.*

##How do I see what elements in an array that matches my regular expression?

There is a function dedicated for just this purpose, `preg_grep`. It will take a regular expression as first parameter, and an array as the second.

See the below example:

```
$haystack = array (
  'say hello',
  'hello stackoverflow',
  'hello world',
  'foo bar bas'
);

$matches  = preg_grep ('/^hello (\w+)/i', $haystack);

print_r ($matches);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [1] => hello stackoverflow
    [2] => hello world
)
```

###Documentation

- [PHP: preg_grep - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

---

##But I just want to get the value of the specified groups. How?

`array_reduce` with `preg_match` can solve this issue in clean manner; see the snippet below.

```
$haystack = array (
  'say hello',
  'hello stackoverflow',
  'hello world',
  'foo bar bas'
);

function _matcher ($m, $str) {
  if (preg_match ('/^hello (\w+)/i', $str, $matches))
    $m[] = $matches[1];

  return $m;
}

// N O T E :
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// you could specify '_matcher' as an anonymous function directly to
// array_reduce though that kind of decreases readability and is therefore
// not recommended, but it is possible.

$matches = array_reduce ($haystack, '_matcher', array ());

print_r ($matches);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stackoverflow
    [1] => world
)
```

**Documentation**

- [PHP: array_reduce - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)
- [PHP: preg_match - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

---

###Using `array_reduce` seems tedious, isn't there another way?

Yes, and this one is actually cleaner though it doesn't involve using any pre-existing `array_*` or `preg_*` function.

Wrap it in a function if you are going to use this method more than once.

```
$matches = array ();

foreach ($haystack as $str) 
  if (preg_match ('/^hello (\w+)/i', $str, $m))
    $matches[] = $m[1];
```

**Documentation**

- [PHP: preg_match - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 8):

Use [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

```
$array = preg_grep(
    '/(my\n+string\n+)/i',
    array( 'file' , 'my string  => name', 'this')
);
```

Answer (score 7):

```php
$haystack = array (
   'say hello',
   'hello stackoverflow',
   'hello world',
   'foo bar bas'
);

$matches  = preg_grep('/hello/i', $haystack);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
   [1] => say hello
   [2] => hello stackoverflow
   [3] => hello world
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_walk` to apply your `preg_match` function to each element of the array.

https://www.php.net/array_walk

Comment: This seems overly complicated for this task.  Youd have to use the callback to delete the non-matchign items.

Answer (score 3):

```
$items = array();
foreach ($haystacks as $haystack) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $haystack, $matches)
        $items[] = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: @OlafErlandsen: How so? You need to examine each element somehow. `foreach` isn't magically expensive for doing that.

Comment: but it doesn't capture the first parenthesized match like you specified?

Answer (score 0):

may be a little longer but I can offer you this version!

```
$array = array (
    'tagid=1' => '1',
    "a" => "a", 
    "b" => "b", 
    "c" => "c",
    'tagid=2' => '2',
);

$regex = '/tagid=[0-9]+/i';

$tags = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $key)) {
        $tags[] = $value;
    }
}

// OUTPUT
$tags = array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2'
);
```