# Check if a specific word is in an array

Tags: php

I am having a a bit of an issue related to checking a returned array for specific matches.

Here is what I do:

I query a server API and the API returns a printable result using:

```
print_r($result);
```

the printed result is:

```
Array
(
    [<html><center>Password_Saved!</center></html>] => 
)
```

So I thought I could do something like:

```
function checkResult ($needle, $haystack) {   return ( stripos($haystack,$needle) !== false ? TRUE : FALSE); }

if ((checkResult("saved",$result))) {
echo "saved";
} else {
echo "not saved";
}
```

However, this does not work at all, so I am wondering if you could help me find a way if the $result contains the string saved since I need to know this to perform the next action based on the result.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `stripos` expects a *string* as the haystack. You pass in *an array*... It gets silently converted to the string `"Array"` (and emits a warning in more recent versions of PHP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you are looking for exists in the array's key instead of value.
As such, you need to be doing your search in the array's keys instead of values.

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value)
{
   if (false !== stripos ($key, "saved"))
   {
      print "{$key} => Saved";
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that correctly addresses the question.

Comment: @BenM :  Why? It's case-insensitive

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks again, this did help me a lot and I actually learned something out of this :)

Answer (score 0):

Read about php [preg_grep function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

For example:

```
$needle_pattern = '/search/i'; // i for case insensitive
preg_grep($needle_pattern, $array_haystack);
```

Also notice that in your code you're mixing "saved" and "Saved" which are different :)

For further reading about this method:

[How to search in an array with preg_match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627334/how-to-search-in-array-with-preg-match)

P.S If your "haystack" is actually the keys, you can switch $array_haystack with [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)($array_haystack) to get an array of all keys.

Comment: This will not work, as `saved` is only a partial match. Also, looking at the printed output he has provided, it looks like `<html><center>Password_Saved!</center></html>` is actually the array **key**, not its value.

Comment: Again, please check the output. This isn't about searching the value of an array, but rather its keys...

Comment: Again, fixed (last comment)

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because your searching for `saved` when the value you have in the string is `Saved`. and you should pass your array key.

```
if ((checkResult("Saved",array_keys($result)[0]))) {
echo "saved";
} else {
echo "not saved";
}
```

Comment: Please check the output of the `$result` array the OP has provided.  It looks like `<html><center>Password_Saved!</center></html>` is actually the array **key**, not its value. Also, this will not return true for a partial match, which is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: No good after the edit, either. `stripos` expects a string, not an array.

Comment: @BenM i don't understand what you mean by match will only be partial

Comment: My bad, didn't realize you were passing the first array key in, I thought you were passing the whole array through.