# PHP Validation String Does Not Contain List Of Values

Tags: php, validation

for example I might:

```
$exclude_values = ['/','.'];
$check_string = 'asdf/';
$return = 'VALID';
foreach($exclude_values as $value)
{
  if(strpos($value,$check_string) != FALSE)
  {
   $return = 'INVALID';
  }
}

return $return;
```

Is there a better way to do this?
I've seen examples of single checks on stack just not multiple values

Comment: You can return invalid inside the IF statement, to skip some iterations

Comment: Yes so instead of $return = 'INVALID' it would go return FALSE or whatever.

Comment: it's certainly better to return boolean than string key :)

Comment: Right, this was written more for visualization than production ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can't recommend any string searching function outside the [multibyte](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) or [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) lib, because they are not always utf-8 compatible, and you'll have strange errors sooner or later.

In your case a regex is a much better solution:

```
return !preg_match('%[/\.]%usD', $check_string);
```

Comment: Can you pass an array of check values?

Comment: Yes, you have to transform them into a regex pattern.

Comment: here is a good reference to that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627334/how-to-search-in-array-with-preg-match

Comment: Pattern modifiers `u`, `s`, and `D` don't appear to serve any purpose in this case.