# PHP: Seeking efficient structure to loop through arrays for match

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have multiple arrays of strings and I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to loop through them for a match and if a match is found, leave the loop.  For each array I'm already using a loop to check for matches. There ought to be a better way to do this than just to repeat the inner loop in code for each and every array but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is my code. It only shows 3 arrays but I'd like to eventually expand this to many more arrays so the code will become more and more inefficient.

```
    $query = $_Request['q'];//query from Internet
    $arrayMovies = array("La Dolce Vita","East of Eden","North by Northwest");
    $arrayDirectors = array("Fellini","Ray","Hitchcock");
    $arrayActors = array("Giancarlo","James","Jimmy");
    $match = "";
    $type = "";
    $phrases = $arrayMovies;

    foreach($phrases as $phrase)
    {
      if(preg_match("/" . $phrase . "/i", $query))
      {
        $match = $phrase;
        $type = "movie";
      }
    }

    //repeat for next array
    $phrases = $arrayDirectors;
    foreach($phrases as $phrase)
    {
      if(preg_match("/" . $phrase . "/i", $query))
      {
        $match = $phrase;
        $type = "director";
      }
    }

    //repeat for next array
    $phrases = $arrayActors;
    foreach($phrases as $phrase)
    {
      if(preg_match("/" . $phrase . "/i", $query))
      {
        $match = $phrase;
        $type = "actor";
      }
    }

    if ($match!="") {
      //DO SOMETHING
    }
```

Is there a way to loop through the arrays and the first time we find a match leave the loop and do something with the match?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search in an array with preg\_match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627334/how-to-search-in-an-array-with-preg-match)

Comment: Aren't your variables in `preg_match` backwards? And simple string matching (`stristr`) should work, given your example.

Comment: The linked to question is about how to get the match which is already working. My issue is with how to manage looping when working with multiple arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two examples here.  You could return early using a function, or breakout a loop.  Note both methods will short-circuit after the first match.

```
<?php

$arrayDirectors = array("Fellini","Ray","Hitchcock");
$arrayMovies    = array("La Dolce Vita","East of Eden","North by Northwest");

function keyword_search($keyword, $array) {
    foreach($array as $value)
        if (preg_match("/\b" . preg_quote($keyword) . "/i", $value))
            return true;
}

if(keyword_search('Hitch', $arrayDirectors))
    echo 'Search term found in directors.';
```

Output:

```
Search term found in directors.
```

To find which collection you obtain a match:

```
<?php
foreach(['directors' => &$arrayDirectors, 'movies' => &$arrayMovies] as $collection => $v)
{
    if(keyword_search('eden', $v)) {
        $matched = $collection;
        break;
    }
}

echo $matched;
```

Output:

```
movies
```

I've added a word boundary to your regex, otherwise it's easy to match prematurely/or over match IMHO.

But you'll probably want to match multiple titles.  In which case you might want to filter your arrays instead:

```
<?php
$arrayMovies = array("North to Alaska","East of Eden","North by Northwest","Westworld");

function keyword_filter($keyword, $array) {
    return array_filter($array, function($value) use ($keyword) {
        return preg_match("/\b" . preg_quote($keyword) . "/i", $value);
    });
}    

var_export(keyword_filter('north', $arrayMovies));
echo "\n";
var_export(keyword_filter('west', $arrayMovies));
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'North to Alaska',
    2 => 'North by Northwest',
)
array (
    3 => 'Westworld',
)
```

Comment: No need for the array_filter/preg_match where preg_grep will do as Jason suggests.

Comment: Any regexers out there, are the brackets needed on the word boundary \b?

Comment: No, word boundaries don't consume any characters so your capturing group would be empty (not that you are using it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge to combine your arrays into a single array. Then you only need to loop through it once. You can use the continue key word to escape the loop when you have found a match.

```
<?php

$query = 'James';//query from Internet
$arrayMovies = array("La Dolce Vita","East of Eden","North by Northwest");
$arrayDirectors = array("Fellini","Ray","Hitchcock");
$arrayActors = array("Giancarlo","James","Jimmy");
$match = null;
$phrases = array_merge($arrayMovies, $arrayDirectors, $arrayActors);

foreach($phrases as $phrase)
{
    if(preg_match("/" . $phrase . "/i", $query))
    {
        $match = $phrase;
        continue;
    }
}

if (!empty($match)) {
    echo 'Found a match for ' . $match;
}
```

Alternatively, you don't need to loop through the array. You can use preg_grep to search your array once it is merged. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Comment: This would work if I could preserve info that I've matched a director or a movie or an actor as I need this.  Can you see a way to preserver which array it came from?

Comment: preg_grep is a great suggestion for a quick filter.